# NodeJS: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]:The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer...Received type number (NaN) how to fix

Tags: node.js, typeerror

This Node JS code is from this project (https://replit.com/@scip10/filledge#index.js).

I got

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type number (NaN)
```

I think the error comes from

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const count = readFileSync('./count.txt','utf-8');
  console.log('count ',count)

  const newCount = parseInt(count) + 1

  writeFileSync('./count.txt', newCount);
```

I'm not too familiar with NodeJS, so please could anyone explain to me how I can change this code to remove the error?

I expected a localhost web page saying

## Welcome to my Website!

## This site has been viewed x times

i tried using .tostring() but it just merge strings which 1+1=11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The "data" argument must be of type string" so you have to convert newCount to string.

```
const { readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require("fs");

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const count = readFileSync("./count.txt", "utf-8");
  console.log("count ", count);

  const newCount = parseInt(count) + 1;

  writeFileSync("./count.txt", newCount.toString());

  res.send(`
      
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
    <head>      
     <meta charset='utf-8' />
     <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' />
     <title>hosted by Rasberry Pi</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Welcome to my Website!<h1>
      <p>This site has been viewed ${newCount} times</p>
    </body>
    </html>
  
  `);
});

app.listen(5000, () => console.log("http://localhost:5000/"));
```

Comment: It didn't show an error but it didn't work as it should. It says 'Welcome to my Website!
This site has been viewed NaN times', as you can see it shows 'NaN' instead of a number. How would i fix that? Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I got the code from: https://fireship.io/lessons/host-website-raspberry-pi/

Comment: I have tested in my system, everything is ok, have you copied the codes above & try in VS code? I am using Window 10 system and VS code, codes above work fine. Thanks

Comment: I got it! I replaced the NaN in the count.txt with a zero initially!

Comment: I couldn't try it on VS code because I'm on my school chromebook pc so I'm currently using replit. But it works anyway! Thank you!